# How do I find the amount of positive integers from 500-5943 that are divisible by 3 or 7 in Python?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm having some trouble. I know if I'm trying to find the number of numbers from 0-1000 that are divisible by 3 or 7 for example I would use the equation np.floor(1000/3)+np.floor(1000/7)-np.floor(1000/21). However, this time the range doesn't start from 0, so what should I replace 1000 with? Thanks! np is numpy btw

Comment: Just find the count from 0 to 5943 and subtract the count from 0 to 499.

Comment: I think you should show some code to give us a feeling that you've tried to work this out first before coming with a question. I think  you don't have to have numpy for solving issues like this.
If you are using `range(1001)` to get numbers from 0 to 1000, you can use `range(start, start + 1001)` to get numbers from start to start + 1000.

Answer (score 0):

O(n) approach:

```
result = 0
for x in range(1001):
    if (x % 3 == 0 and x % 7 == 0):
        result += 1
print(result)
```

More concise:

`result = sum(x % 3 == 0 and x % 7 == 0 for x in range(1001))`

Comment: Divisible by 3 *or* 7, not 3 *and* 7.